# Link to Excel from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was wondering is there a way to link an Access query to an Excel sheet that automatically updates when the query changes? I know you can link and Excel sheet to an Access table and it updates automatically. I'm just wondering if it can be done the other way with a link?

Comment: [linked worksheets are read-only from Access' perspective](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34932921/77335)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing SQL updates on linked Excel table in Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932034/executing-sql-updates-on-linked-excel-table-in-access)